# Installing wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage on SmartOS (Joyent)

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage, smartos

How can I install wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage on SmartOS (Joyent)?  I would like to use these with the [node-wkhtml](https://github.com/traviscooper/node-wkhtml) module.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, because there aren't available binary packages (from start page of named projects):

> Download a precompiled binary or build from source
>
> In case you are running on ... another Unix-like OS, you will need to use the  posix-local  target. It assumes that you already have all the build dependencies installed beforehand and will generate a tarball with the specification of  local-MACHINENAME  in the  static-build/  folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found another solution or not, but I've recently compiled a static version of wkhtmltopdf (version from Github) with the custom Qt modules. Mailing list thread is here: [Static Build - SmartOS Base64 14.1.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wkhtmltopdf-general/AIagbMp-FJw)